# searchkick Index missing in ruby application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, elasticsearch, searchkick

Im trying to use Searchkick in my application. However, I get

```
Searchkick::MissingIndexError
```

Index missing - `run Product.reindex`

```
def search
  if params[:search].present?
    @product = Product.search(params[:search])
  else
    @product = Product.all
  end
```

I run Produc.reindex but it didn't solve the issue. I also tried following : `rake searchkick:reindex:all` and I receive the `Reindex complete` message which is followed by `rake db:migrate`; however,I come up with the same missing index error when I submit the search query.

any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: was it ever working? if not - have you configured searchkick properly like setting elasticsearch URL et cetera? have you check in the logs what happens when you run `Product.reindex` ?

Comment: thanks @mkozak for the tips

Comment: I have the same problem. I can search in rails console, but same code in the controller returns `Searchkick::MissingIndexError` error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Finally found the solution. I was running my app in staging environment and did the Item.reindex in production console. `RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rails c` and then `Item.reindex` solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Using Rails 4.1.8 and Elastic Search 2.4.6, I was facing this same problem in the production environment, and when I tried to access the action URL of the autocomplete action I was receiving the same `Index missing - run Product.reindex` error message. However, in development environment Elastic Search was working without problems.

Usually, I use the following command to reindex my class:

```
rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Product
```

So, following @Aref Aslani comment, I tried this command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Product
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply launch your **Rails Console** and then type

```
Product.reindex
```

I had a similar error in my application and so I just decided to understand the error message and then tried it on the console as if I am testing a feature and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue in the rails development environment, Rails 5.2.3, ruby 2.4.0, so 
resolved it by using the following command:

```
rails searchkick:reindex CLASS=<ClassName>
```

like

```
rails searchkick:reindex CLASS=ThreeDGarment
```